# Is it possible to have few root folders for one application? Android

Tags: android, package, sandbox

Is it possible to have few root folders for one application? 
For example i have package `com.xxx.yyy` and package `com.zzz.ooo` in one .apk.
So is it possible to have two root folders like `/data/data/com.xxx.yyy` and `/data/data/com.zzz.ooo` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will base the package name on your file system of the `package="com.packagename.android"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

So although you can have as many different java packages in your src these are dex'd, the android package is only set from your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Reason is that your resource files are generated to a singular package.

Different build system this might be possible.. but not currently with ADT/Ant.